# Wordpress error after installing plugin "Internal Server Error"

Tags: plugins, errors, 500-internal-error

So after I press "Install" on a plugin that I want to install to my page I get "Internal Server Error" and message, that the plugin already exists. (Even I am installing a plugin for the first time, there is no folder in wp_content and plugin.) Even, that there was an error message, the plugin is installed and all I have to do in "Activate" it in plugins tab.

So, I can install any plugin anyway but is it annoying, that I have error message every time. Can I fix that somehow?

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try to deactivate all other plugins, revert to a default theme like `TwentySeventeeen` and test once more? If this resolves the error, it should be a conflict with some theme and/or plugin(s). Simply activate them back one-by-one checking each time the installation process until you get the error again.

Also, check that you are running the last version of WordPress.

Comment: It was caused by plugin called "WP statistics" maybe they messed up something in the last update. Thank you a lot =)

Comment: Glad to know you figure it out ;)